# Fetch latest snapshot asset by Nexus Repository API

Tags: repository, sonatype, nexus3

I'm using Nexus API to fetch snapshots versions, 
and I'm looking for a way to get the `asset` of the latest `snapshot` record.
But I couldn't find it in the API documentation (https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/rest-and-integration-api/search-api#SearchAPI-SearchAssets)

I did find a request to download the latest asset, but it doesn't help because I want the `json` of the latest asset itself.
I don't know if they even support that kind of request at all.

If someone knows what the trick here it would be really helpful.

Comment: See the bottom of this page for an example:  https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/Search+API#SearchAPI-DownloadingtheLatestVersionofanAsset

Comment: @rseddon It doesn't return a `json` as the response

Comment: Use /search/assets rather than /search/assets/download if you want a JSON response.